# How can I test multiple fake users accessing my WCF service?

Tags: c#-3.0, performance

I'm building a WCF service I'm concerned about performance and scalability.

In order to test multiple users accessing my WCF Service, what should I do?

- create a Thread Pool to run separated threads which in turn access the same WCF method?
- use a testing software tool to simulate these fake users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would much rather use some stress testing tool to not reinvent the wheel. It will probably be easier to maintain and such tools may provide for mechanisms to (on a later stage) move your calling clients to several machines etc. Also, they may provide a better way of analyzing the data.

[Here](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/) is one free WCF load test tool, has several downloads but not a high rating. I would at least check it out before you writer your own.

Answer (score 0):

What protocol is your WCF service using?
If nettcp, you can try [WCF Storm](http://www.wcfstorm.com)

For httpbinding, there's plenty on the market:
[HPE LoadRunner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIjZLLzK7XAhVLro8KHSVHCEgQFgh4MA4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoftware.microfocus.com%2Fen-us%2Fsoftware%2Floadrunner%2Ftry-now&usg=AOvVaw3icEaJ_AgYze6HV0KvTn8q)

[Telerik TestStudio](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj2z5PhzK7XAhUJqI8KHauADkkQFgg-MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.telerik.com%2Fvideos%2Fteststudio%2Fload-testing-web-services-with-telerik-test-studio&usg=AOvVaw24Y_SJkvEUTsZdVIHEuLEo)